# When typing in a new window letters are missing in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

So, we have this large webmail client built using AngularJS. We have a multi window compose feature. When the email is composed inside of the main IE tab where the app is running everything is smooth. However, when we're typing anything (recipient fields, message body etc) in the separate compose window (same shared code as the main app: controllers, factories etc) we have severe issues with missing letters (as if the event never occurred) and we can't figure out what's going on since we're using a shared code base for that message composer and it works great when not isolated in a separate window.

Other browsers work just fine. Any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: Share some of the relevant code, what steps have you taken in debugging so far have you added key-up listeners are you just using ng-model on inputs did you try using ngModelChange to see if the model is being updated.  Need a lot more detail to reproduce the problem not just an explanation of what the issue appears to be.

Comment: When writing an SO question I think it's best to think of it as a bug report and include all the code and steps necessary to reproduce the problem or you won't likely get any positive feedback.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Roger that but I'm legally not allowed to share any specific code, I'm sorry. Nonetheless, the same thing happens in Edge. We're just using simple ng-model binding, ng-change isn't used anywhere. We'll go ahead and try with ngModelChange.

Comment: ...actually, ngModelChange seems to be Angular-specific, not AngularJS so that's a no-go.